# Ubuntu WSL on Windows 10 shows 2 x 256 GB drives though only one 256 GB drive is installed

Tags: disk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed Ubuntu on Windows 10 using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

When I run the `lslbk` command, I see the following:

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0  256G  0 disk  
sdb    8:16   0  256G  0 disk /
```

However, in Windows Disk Management, there is only one hard disk installed. I'm confused why the Ubuntu WSL shows the aforementioned output.

Answer (score 2):

Both drives are virtual disks in WSL2, as WSL doesn't allow direct access to the underlying Windows host drive/hardware.  WSL1's `lsblk` just errors out, while WSL2 (which you are apparently using) at least makes an attempt to map the virtual disk to its proper Linux device.

There are (belatedly, I realize, from a new comment) two questions involved here:

- Why do you have multiple virtual disks in WSL?
- Why is the sum of the sizes of the drives larger than that of the real drive?

##### The multiple virtual disks

`/dev/sdb`, as can be seen in your `lsblk` output, is your root filesystem for this particular WSL instance.  If you were to start another instance (by installing a distribution or cloning your existing one), you would see a third drive (in all instances).  You can also see it being "attached" through `dmesg`.

With a default Ubuntu on WSL installation, the `/dev/sdb` for the instance corresponds to the `ext4.vhdx` file in your `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\<distribution_package>\LocalState\` directory.  If you create your own instances with `wsl --import`, it's possible to place the file anywhere.

`/dev/sda` is, I'm fairly certain, the swap drive (credit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/h7s06k/somehow_i_have_2_drives_in_wsl_why/)).  This drive is shared across all WSL instances.  You can find this virtual disk in `%temp%\swap.vhdx`.  Although I don't recommend it, you can confirm this with:

```
cat /proc/swaps # shows that the swap file is "/swap/file"
sudo mkdir /mnt/tmpmount
sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt/tmpmount
ls /mnt/tmpmount # shows the "file" is the only thing on the drive
```

Under a typical Linux installation, this would be more apparent through the mount in `/etc/fstab`, but this seems to be one of the things WSL handles through its own (bit-of-a-black-box) `/init`.

##### The size of the disks

The virtual disks that are created under WSL are "dynamic", meaning that they don't actually take 256GB on the drive.  If you have used, for instance, 3GB of space inside Ubuntu, then the "real" size of the VHD will be around 3GB.  It can grow (dynamically) up to 256GB, *assuming there is space on the parent drive*.  *(Side-note:  Recent WSL versions increase the default virtual disk size to 1TB.)*

The *dynamic* size of the virtual disk can even exceed the physical space available on the host.  If you run out of space on the parent drive, but Ubuntu still thinks it has space available, WSL will (if I recall correctly) set the drive read-only.  You'll see errors to this effect when you try to run commands that create (or grow) files.

This allows you to have, for example, three WSL distributions to be installed, each with a dynamic, virtual 256GB (now 1TB) drive, on a host that doesn't have that much space available.

Note that the drives will grow, but they cannot shrink on their own when you remove files from Ubuntu.  For more information on that, see [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/1606213/1210833).

Comment: But why doesn't `/swap` directory even exist? How is swap used without this drive being mounted there by default? Should it be mounted by hand to be used?

Comment: @lem0nify That's a really good question, but with an answer just complicated enough that I think it needs its own Q&A.  Would you mind posting that as a new question?  I think [Super User](https://superuser.com) would probably be best, but if you want to post it here on AU, I won't mind answering it here either.  As long as it's tagged [windows-subsystem-for-linux] or a related tag, I should see it.  Thanks!

Comment: Done: https://superuser.com/questions/1714405/drive-dev-sda-with-a-swap-file-in-wsl2
Can not wait for your reply. :)

Comment: in my case it shows 4x 256G and only one 120G is installed.

Comment: @webduvet Do you have more than one WSL distribution installed?  (`wsl -l -v`)  If I had to take a guess, you have (1) your installed distribution, (2) the swap drive, (3) `docker-desktop`, and (4) `docker-desktop-data`?

Comment: yes I have 3 distros installed as far as I remember. I'm not on the machine right now, but 3 distros + 1 swap drive makes up 4. It makes sense.

Comment: @webduvet I just realized that you may really be questioning how the size of the 4 virtual disks can be larger than the host drive.  Added that to my answer, in case you were wondering ;-)